# running Matlab in bash script; matlab: not found

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, ubuntu

The code to run matlab in bash script:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "run ./myDir/myfile ; quit;"
```

I have Matlab installed on my computer, however when I run the bash script I get this error:

```
matlab:not found
```

I don't know if it is because of the Matlab's path (`/home/myComputerName/Documents/MATLAB/bin/matlab`) in my computer, which is located under /Documents/.

What causes this problem? If it is because of the path, is there a general solution, i.e. running matlab is independent where it is installed, for this?

Comment: pls run `which matlab` or `whereis matlab` to see if you have `matlab` in your `path` and installed in your machine. You can always add `/Documents` to your `PATH` if you have `matlab` there and dnt want to type `./Documents/matlab`

Comment: Nothing appears! It is interesting because I have matlab installed.

Comment: where is your `matlab`'s executable (the path)?

Comment: /Documents/MATLAB/bin/matlab

Comment: run this `export PATH=$PATH:/Documents/MATLAB/bin/matlab` and then run `matlab` from the cmd prompt. Let me know if this works.

Comment: `matlab: command not found`

Comment: did the output of `which matlab` change? Do you have `matlab` for Unix installed properly?

Comment: nothing happens with `which matlab`. Yes, matlab 32-bit unix

Comment: I am guessing you have some problems with installation. Sorry, not sure about the problem you are facing. May be uninstall and reinstall the package and make sure you follow the steps properly. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: Thanks anyway, for your time.

Comment: A directory called `/Documents` seems unlikely to exist on an Ubuntu install. Are you sure it isn't actually in `$HOME/Documents`? If so, that needs to go in the path line.

Comment: it is in `/home/myComputerName/Documents`

Comment: Try `export PATH=$PATH:/home/myComputerName/Documents/MATLAB/bin` then

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is to add the directory containing the binary to your `PATH`, or, conversely, to properly install the program so that it appears in a directory which is already included in your `PATH`.  For locally installed software, the standard location is `/usr/local/bin`.

Typically you would edit your `.bashrc` and log out and back in to update your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Try matlab support, it just solved a lot of my  path/launcher related issues

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```